# ASP.Net Core: set default culture from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-localization

I am trying to set up localization in my ASP.Net Core Web API project.

I did some research and understand that there is a localization middleware with predefined request culture providers (which in my case are not acceptable), so I need to write a custom request culture provider, something like

```
public class CustomCultureProvider : RequestCultureProvider
{
    public override async Task<ProviderCultureResult> ChangeCulture(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        // Return a culture...
        return new ProviderCultureResult("en-US");
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is how I can change the culture from a controller, that is, when an endpoint is called.

Comment: Why doesn't the standard localisation middleware work for you?

Comment: @Neil Cookies and browser header are not an option, and I also don't want client apps to have to append the culture code to every request. I want to enable changing the culture in one go.

Comment: The browser is going to have to send *some* information about the user, otherwise how will you know which culture to select for each request?

Comment: @Neil Well of course it's going to send some information, but I don't want to retrieve culture info from the data that the browser *automatically* sends in a request, but explicitly from a call to an endpoint I defined.

Comment: @Eutherpy but you *are* using the localization middleware. The custom culture provider is used only to specify the culture using your own rules so the rest of the middleware can work. You shouldn't care about when the localization middleware is called. So *what* are your rules? What does `change the culture from a controller` mean? That's not a rule, that's how you thing the change would be done.

Comment: For example, do you want to change the culture based on a part of the URL (eg en-us), the way documentation sites do? Or change it based on a user setting the way forums do?

Comment: Hi @Eutherpy,did you resolve your issue now?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working demo for asp.net core 3.x that could switch three languages to display the response:

1.Custom `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider`:

```
public class CustomRouteDataRequestCultureProvider : RequestCultureProvider
{
    public int IndexOfCulture;
    public override Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));
        string culture = null;


        var twoLetterCultureName = httpContext.Request.Path.Value.Split('/')[IndexOfCulture]?.ToString();

        if (twoLetterCultureName == "de" )
            culture = twoLetterCultureName;
        else if (twoLetterCultureName == "fr")
            culture = twoLetterCultureName;
        else if(twoLetterCultureName =="en")
            culture = twoLetterCultureName;

        if (culture == null)
            return NullProviderCultureResult;          

        var providerResultCulture = new ProviderCultureResult(culture);

        return Task.FromResult(providerResultCulture);
    }
}
```

2.Startup.cs:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

    services.AddControllers().AddViewLocalization(
    LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
    opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => {
        var supportedCultures = new CultureInfo[] {
            new CultureInfo("en"),
            new CultureInfo("de"),
            new CultureInfo("fr")
    };
        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

        options.RequestCultureProviders = new[]{ new CustomRouteDataRequestCultureProvider{
            IndexOfCulture=1,
        }};
    });                      
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
    app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute("LocalizedDefault", "{culture:cultrue}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    });          
}
```

Test the project:

1.Create folder `Resources/Controllers`.

2.Create resource file and named as `[ControllerName].[Language].resx` like below:
[image]

3.Edit the content of resource file(i.e. ValuesController.de.resx):
[image]

4.Create a Controller:

```
[Route("{culture?}/api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<ValuesController> _localizer;

    public ValuesController(IStringLocalizer<ValuesController> localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }
    // GET: api/<controller>
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return new ObjectResult(_localizer["Hi"]);
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]