# .NET Core: Edm.Date usage in parameters list generates wrong Swagger document

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, .net-6.0, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Assuming this controller

```cs
    [HttpGet("byDate")]
    public IActionResult Send([Required] [FromQuery] Date date)
    {
        return Ok(date);
    }
```

I was hoping to get usual bindind for string (eg pass "2020-12-31), while swagger generates document with  3 parameters - YEar, Month and Day.

What  is the most common way to allow this object to be passed as pure string?

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60578862/swagger-netcore-3-1-in-web-api-set-the-date-time-format-with-swagger-ui

Comment: Nope, unfortunately. Changing format for single parameter is simple, but I need to change presentation in schema forultiple items, in other words instead of 3 'in' parameters (Year, Month, Day) I would like to have one parameterName with value string and date kind

Comment: The [OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/) defines the following types:string,number,integer,boolean,array,object.There's no Date type.The string type includes dates and files.So, if use Swagger to document the Date or Datetime type parameter, you could use string or object type. If using string type, try to set the description or add example to format the input, check [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0).If using object type, you have to use 3 parameters (Year, Month and Day).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question, but let me answer it myself.
I will show the code based on .net 6 template

So we will need to add type converter (for correct display in swagger) and json converter (for serializing in response)

```cs
public class DateTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        return Date.Parse(value as string);
    }
}

public class DateConverter : JsonConverter<Date>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => typeof(Date) == objectType;

    public override Date Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        reader.GetDateTime();

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Date value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
}
```

And register them with application

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers() .AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DateConverter());
});
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(Date), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(DateTypeConverter)));
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(opts =>
{
    opts.MapType(typeof(Date), () => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "string", Format = "date" });
    opts.MapType(typeof(Date?), () => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "string", Format = "date" });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```