# How to get the DateTime (with this format dd-MM-yyyy ) in Swagger in ASP.NET Core / C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime

I'm trying to get `DateTime` with a custom format

```
    [HttpGet("{date}")]
    public ActionResult<int> ToMarsDate(DateTime date)
    {
        // date in here equals : "2023-06-10T21:53:28.331Z";
        // But I want to receive the input in this format :   
        // 10-06-2023 (dd-MM-yyyy)
    }
```

Can you help me?

Comment: `DateTime` objects don't have a format associated with them. You can format them when you render them as a string (for example, with `ToString`) and you can read a string to create a DateTime (for example with `TryParseExact`)

Comment: maybe this is post help you(use AddNewtonsoftJson) ,https://stackoverflow.com/a/60595858/10193401

Answer (score 0):

try using `date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`